# What to conclude about the results if the p-value is same in 2 Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am comparing observed and simulated acceleration distributions. There are 3 data sets:

1) `acco` = observed accelerations
2) `acc15` = simulated accelerations data 1
3) `acc16` = simulated accelerations data 2

I did 2 sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with `acco` & `acc15`, and then `acco` and `acc16`. I want to see which of the two simulated acceleration distribution is (more) similar to the observed. I guess it is important to note here that both simulations were calibrated using the observed data using different methods. Here are the test results:

```
> ks.test(acco$slo_v_m, acc15$saccm)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  acco$slo_v_m and acc15$saccm
D = 0.23379, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(acco$slo_v_m, acc15$saccm) :
  p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties
> ks.test(acco$slo_v_m, acc16$saccm)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  acco$slo_v_m and acc16$saccm
D = 0.37959, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(acco$slo_v_m, acc16$saccm) :
  p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties
```

You can see that both resulted in same p-value but different D statistic. What can I conclude about these data? Can I say that`acc15` is better than `acc16` when compared with `acco`?

Comment: These p-values tell you neither distribution is anything like the reference distribution.  This is somewhat like asking us which is more like a crow: a pencil or a stick of chewing gum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These P-values aren't the same, they are just both less than $2.2 \times 10^{-16}$. From this I would conclude:

1. As whuber said, neither acc15 nor acc16 is a good fit to acco.
2. Your software isn't very carefully coded. It's probably computing a right tail probability as 1 minus a left cumulative probability, which means it can't, in normal double-precision arithmetic, compute any P-value less than $\sim 10^{-16}$, and already looses a lot of accuracy for values greater than that.